# Illustrator | Automate .ai files export with batch

Tags: export, adobe-illustrator

I have a file that has 100+ `.ai` separate files that I want to export each one of them into a PNG file using `save for web`.
is there any possible way to automate this using batch or any other method ?

Comment: Have you tried recording an action and running it as a batch?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad yes but I can't override the save button, I want to fully automate the process

Comment: See this [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/67871/how-to-save-for-web-multiple-illustrator-files-with-illustrator-script)

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18789668/how-to-write-a-script-that-does-save-for-web-for-mutiple-resolutions-in-adobe#19953303) may also prove useful